# images joined together, align properly

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

i tried to adjust the images of category by modifying the vqmod in 100x100 to 200x200 and this what happen, i use the display: block, float: left; but im not lucky to fix it.

i also tried to adjust the col-sm-2 and i added the d-inline and its not working. instead of using the css code or the stylesheet, i added the code here. can someone show me the code to fix it? thank you and regards to all

[image: here is the image]

```html
<modification>
 <id>Subcategory Images for OC 2.0</id>
 <version>1.0</version>
 <vqmver>1.2.3</vqmver>
 <author>vger.co.uk</author>
 
 <file name="catalog/controller/product/category.php">
        <operation>
            <search position="replace" index="1" offset="3"><![CDATA[
$data['categories'][] = array(
            ]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[
    if ($result['image']) {
     $image = $this->model_tool_image->resize($result['image'], 200, 200);
    } else {
     $image = $this->model_tool_image->resize('placeholder.png', 100, 100);
    }
    
    $data['categories'][] = array(
     'name'  => $result['name'] . ($this->config->get('config_product_count') ? ' (' . $this->model_catalog_product->getTotalProducts($filter_data) . ')' : ''),
     'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . '_' . $result['category_id'] . $url),
     'thumb' => $image
    );
            ]]></add>
        </operation>
 </file>
 
 <file name="catalog/view/theme/*/template/product/category.tpl">
        <operation>
            <search position="replace" index="1" offset="25"><![CDATA[
<?php if ($categories) { ?>
            ]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[
<?php if ($categories) { ?>
 <div class="col-sm-12">
   <div>
  <h3><?php echo $text_refine; ?></h3>
   </div>
   <div style="text-align: center;">
  <div class="row">
  <?php foreach ($categories as $category) { ?>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-6 d-inline" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
   <a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $category['thumb']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $category['name']; ?>" /></a>
   <a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a>
    </div>
  <?php } ?>
  </div>
   </div>
 </div>
<?php } ?>
            ]]></add>
        </operation>
 </file>
 
</modification>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<div class="img-responsive inline-block;" style="border:">
    <a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $category['thumb']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $category['name']; ?>" /></a>
   </div>
```